# Why is X509Certificate2.Import(Filename) unable to load a Symlink Certificate

Tags: c#, symlink, x509certificate2

I'm trying to Import a certificate (Using the Symbolic Link of the actual Certificate).

However I'm ending up with this Below Exception.

```
Unspecified error
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import(String fileName)
```

The work around I'm doing is to load the contents of the file and call Import using byte[].

```
publicCertificate = new X509Certificate2();

// If the File is a Symbolic Link, then read the byte[]
if (new FileInfo(publicFilePath).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint))
{
    publicCertificate.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(publicFilePath));
}
else
{
    publicCertificate.Import(publicFilePath); // This Throws Error without the above Condition
}
```

I looked at the documentation of this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Import_System_String_) and there seems to be no mentioning of it not working on Symlink files.

Is there some configuration I can feed to X509Certificates and directly Import the certificate instead of manually reading its contents?

Comment: Because [CryptQueryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject) fails with a symbolic link. If we go one element deeper, then no idea.